# Implementing revisioning logic with SCD2/4

Tags: postgresql, slowly-changing-dimension

I posted this question on StackOverflow, but it didn't get much luck so I'm hoping I could have better luck here.

I'm working on a project that is a sort of bill of materials manager that needs to support revisioning of components.  After some research, I've stumbled upon slowly changing dimensions type 2 and type 4 which seems like the most appropriate pattern in this use cases.

However, I'm a little bit confused on a couple of concepts:

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
  id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name  TEXT
)

CREATE TABLE components (
  id           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name         TEXT,
  project_id   INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT fk_project FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES projects (id)
)
```

If I wanted to implement SCD Type 2, would the components table have the additional columns for `start_date`, `end_date`, `active`?  Or, would Type 2 be adding a `revisions` table with the same structure as `components` with the additional columns and Type 4 having a `revisions` table and a `revisions_history` table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Original SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69057139/implementing-revisioning-with-scd2-4

From your comment in that post (which should be copied into your question here -- please edit your question), it sounds like you want audit/history tables so you can revert edits to any particular object. These are typically implemented using triggers; extensions like [pgaudit](https://www.pgaudit.org/) can manage these for you.

That said, I recommend taking a step back, identifying your business processes, and implementing the operations that make sense for your project managers. You can write a complicated system that allows reverting anything and end up with projects that never existed.