# How can I diff two rows in a SCD (Type2) Postgres db?

Tags: postgresql

We have a set of 5 tables that are set up for SCD (slowly changing dimensions). So the PK is an ID field and to get the most current version of the row you get the row with the highest value for ID. Nothing gets deleted or updated, everything is an insert with a new ID. The "semantic ID" of the record is not the ID.

I'd like to compare the **n**th record with the **n-1**th record to see what changed between the two, if any. Are there tools for this? Should I just serialize the record to JSON and diff the two JSON docs?

[Related thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299089/implementing-revisioning-logic-with-scd2-4).

Comment: if someone with more rep wants to edit and add & create the scd2 tag that would be helpful

Comment: You can [edit] the question yourself. Finding the nth record is always `O(n)`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I can't create tags that's why I said "**with more rep** ... add & **create** the scd2 tag"